# Stop animation gradient css

Tags: css, background, gradient

I would like to know how I can stop a background gradient animation in CSS once the loop is finished. For example, in my CSS I set the animation duration to 12s and 10s. So I would like that once these seconds are over, the animation stops and the background remains with still colors. Thanks! My CSS code:
[css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPkOK.png)

Comment: You have the animation iteration count at infinite - do you want it to be 1? If you want the final state of the animation to be remembered then look into animation-fill-mode: forwards

Comment: Thanks!! Resolved